# Binding a commands canexecute to IDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm

## Edit

I might have complicated things a little so lets keep it simple. If you bind an integer to a textbox it will get a validation exception if you type an illegal character into the textbox. How can I disable a button depending on whether a property has a validation exception.

## original question#

I'm creating an app in WPF with a MVVM approach but without any framework.

My model classes implement IDataErrorInfo,  and if an error occurs all have a HasError property and a Dictionary of < propertyName, ErrorMessage >. If the HasError property changes I RaiseCanExecuteChanged on my Commands to re-evaluate if we now for instance can Save.

This works fine but only for explicit data annotations like

```
  [MaxLength(3,ErrorMessage = "The text can't be longer than 3")]
  [CustomRequiredAttribute]
  public string CountryCode
  {
     get { return m_CountryCode; }
     set { SetProperty(ref m_CountryCode, value); }
  }
  public string m_CountryCode;
```

If I on the other hand have an Integer bound to a textbox and enter an illegal character like a letter the OnValidate function won't trigger and so the error is not added to my collection.

## How do i capture all validation errors and add to my collection?

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
{
   get
   {
      var error = OnValidate(propertyName);

      return error;
   }
}
```

Here is my CanExecute

```
  protected override bool CanHandleSaveCommand()
  {
     return !Feeds.Any(e => e.HasErrors) && IsEdited;
  }
```

Just so you get the complete picture here is the OnValidate method which works fine

```
protected virtual string OnValidate(string propertyName)
  {
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid property name", propertyName);
     }

     var error_summary = new StringBuilder();
     PropertyInfo property_info = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
     var value = property_info.GetValue(this);
     var validation_errors = new List<ValidationResult>();
     var is_valid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
         value,
         new ValidationContext(this, null, null)
         {
            MemberName = propertyName
         },
         validation_errors);

     if (is_valid)
     {
        if (Errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
           Errors.Remove(propertyName);
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasErrors"));
           HasErrorsChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
     }
     else
     {
        validation_errors.ForEach(e => error_summary.Append(e.ErrorMessage));

        if (Errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
           Errors[propertyName] = error_summary.ToString();
        else
           Errors.Add(propertyName, error_summary.ToString());

        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HasErrors"));
        HasErrorsChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

     }

     return error_summary.ToString();
  }
```

Comment: Please check my edit out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the answer I was looking for. As I stated previously if you enter an illegal character your property is never set. A conversion error exception is thrown by the WPF framework and added to the Validation.Errors collection but no custom validation code will ever be invoked. You have to use the [UpdateSourceExceptionFilter Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourceexceptionfiltercallback(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding 
         UpdateSourceExceptionFilter="ReturnExceptionHandler"
         Path="CurrencyPotens"
         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
         ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"></Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And in the code-behind I can cast my bound object to my NotifyPropertyChanged class and add the Error which in turn will cause my ICommands CanExecute to reevaluate.

```
  public object ReturnExceptionHandler(object bindingExpression, Exception exception)
  {
     BindingExpression be = bindingExpression as BindingExpression;
     var boundItem = be.DataItem;
     ((Wrapper.NotifyPropertyChanged)boundItem).Errors.Add(be.ResolvedSourcePropertyName, exception.Message);

     return exception.Message;
  }
```

Right now I can't get this to work with my MVVM approach so I'm stuck with a little code in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not called since UI isn't aware if there was some error. What I usually do is implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in my VM. When a property is changed I vaidate `value` in the property setter. Then I fire `INotifyDataErrorInfo.ErrorsChangedEvent` if neccessary. Thus UI knows about error and react accordingly

Of course you still can use `IDataErrorInfo` behind the scenes. Hope this helps

**EDIT**

I got your point. I cant get you a solution right now but may give you a direction. I suggest looking at [Overriding metadata technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754209(v=vs.100).aspx) and [Dependency propery callbacks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745795(v=vs.100).aspx). So you override `TextBox.TextProperty` metadata and use your custom callback to set errors.

I'll get back to this issue when i have free time

Comment: But isn't the INotifyDataErrorInfo for validation like start date can't come after end date and such? WPF validates according to type i.e. Integers can't contain "Hello" I can display those errors but how do you bind to them?

Comment: Sorry, but Im not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. If you need just to show these errors somewhere use `<Validation.ErrorTemplate>` [like here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19490.validating-data-in-wpf-4-5-using-the-inotifydataerrorinfo-interface.aspx) .

Comment: I might have muddled my question somewhat, but yes that's what I'm doing but apart from showing there is an error I need to disable my save button. All of which works for the Data Annotations that I've written. But not when i type a letter into a textbox bound to an integer

Comment: If you are already implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` along with `IDataErrorInfo`, then add a boolean that tracks whether errors exist and whenever you update your validation, fire a `PropertyChanged` event for that property.  Bind that property to the button `IsEnabled` property

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but when you type an illegal char in to a integer text box the integer property is never set (how could it, "hello" can't be convert to an integer) and you can't do an evaluation on set property and IDataErrorInfo is never triggered. So how do you bind to the conversion error picked up by the WPF framework?